# How to save Scala List object in session for Scala Play framework

Tags: scala, session, playframework

I am new to Scala and Play framework and working on first web application using Play Framework.

And I am looking for, How to save a Scala List object into session object? I see request.session has method for adding key-value but available for both String values. But my requirement is to add and list Object to session, so that I can access anywhere of the application.

Please help out with sample code here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no server side session in Play. Please see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash

Comment: If so, how to save object which can be accessed through out the application for that user?

Comment: You can store some hash list (simple string) in user cookies and keep hash map of this lists on server side.

Answer (score 0):

The Play session is in fact just a cookie so you should not use it to store "alot" of data. You can only keep 4kb of data in the Play "Session".

Answer (score 0):

Your only solution is to encode the list into a string and parse it back.  Alternatively, you could store a mapping from UUIDs to lists in a global variable on the server, and put the UUID of the list you want to recover into the session, and use that UUID to retrieve the list from your server-side cache when you want the list.